# Android: Adding/removing items dynamically from dialog after it has been displayed

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog that retrieve data from several web services and populate the data to the user to choose.

I would like to show the dialog immediately, and populate the data as they comes in from the web services.  There are possibilities that some of the web services can be down and there is no reason to wait for everything services to return before displaying data to the user.

onPrepareDialog only allows you to change the data before the dialog is actually displayed.  Is there a way I can dynamically add/remove items from the dialog after it has been displayed?

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the dialog? If you put TextView(s) in it you can use `dialog.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);` once the dialog has been shown to get a reference to the TextView. You could then call `setText(txt);` on this reference whenever you want including after some of your webservices have returned.